# Error: request for member ... in ... which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Just started learning c++ for a class, I can't figure out what is wrong with this code! I'm making a stack class with a helper class nested inside it called node that acts as a linked list.  The error I'm getting is on line 12 and is:

> Stack.cpp: In destructor â€˜Stack::~Stack()â€™:
>   Stack.cpp:12:24: error: request for member â€˜getNextâ€™ in â€˜((Stack*)this)->Stack::nodeâ€™, which is of non-class type â€˜Stack::Node*â€™

Here's my code:

```
#include "Stack.h"

Stack:: Stack ()
{
  height = 0;
  node = 0;
}

Stack:: ~Stack()
{
  while(node != 0){
    Node *next = *node.getNext();
    delete node;
    node = next;
  }
  node = 0;
}
```

And Here's my header file:

```
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
 private:
  int height;
  class Node{
    private:
      int data;
      Node* next;
    public:
      void setData(int x){
        data = x;
      }
      void setNext(Node* x){
        next = x;
      }
      int getData(){
        return data;
      }
      Node* getNext(){
        return next;
      }
    };
  Node* node;
public:
  Stack();
  ~Stack();
  void push(int x);
  int pop();
  int peek();
  int getHeight();
  bool isEmpty();
};
```

Comment: I wish I could mark questions as duplicates of this webpage: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Node *next = *node.getNext();
```

should be

```
Node *next = (*node).getNext();
```

Since `.` operator has higher precedence than `*` deference operator.

You can also use:

```
Node *next = node->getNext();
```